# .NET5 WebAPI not connecting to SQL Server on Linux (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, ubuntu

I am trying to connect from .NET5 WebAPI (running on Ubuntu 20.04) to SQL Server Express Edition running on the same computer. So when I try to update database with migrations I get an error. If someone can please try to help me.

Error that I get when applying migrations:

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)
 ---> System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (00000005, 0xFFFDFFFF): Name or service not known
   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntryOrAddressesCore(String hostName, Boolean justAddresses)
   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(String hostNameOrAddress)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNITCPHandle.Connect(String serverName, Int32 port, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean isInfiniteTimeout, String cachedFQDN, SQLDNSInfo& pendingDNSInfo) in H:\tsaagent1\_work\21\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netcore\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SNI\SNITcpHandle.cs:line 305
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNITCPHandle..ctor(String serverName, Int32 port, Int64 timerExpire, Object callbackObject, Boolean parallel, String cachedFQDN, SQLDNSInfo& pendingDNSInfo) in H:\tsaagent1\_work\21\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netcore\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SNI\SNITcpHandle.cs:line 156
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) in H:\tsaagent1\_work\21\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netcore\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlInternalConnection.cs:line 612 
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) in H:\tsaagent1\_work\21\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netcore\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\TdsParser.cs:line 1302
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover, SqlAuthenticationMethod authType) in H:\tsaagent1\_work\21\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netcore\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\TdsParser.cs:line 447
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) in H:\tsaagent1\_work\21\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netcore\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlInternalConnectionTds.cs:line 1860
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) in H:\tsaagent1\_work\21\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netcore\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlInternalConnectionTds.cs:line 1501
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) in H:\tsaagent1\_work\21\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netcore\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlInternalConnectionTds.cs:line 1395
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken, DbConnectionPool pool) in H:\tsaagent1\_work\21\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netcore\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlInternalConnectionTds.cs:line 508
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) in H:\tsaagent1\_work\21\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netcore\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlConnectionFactory.cs:line 133
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) in H:\tsaagent1\_work\21\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netcore\src\Common\src\Microsoft\Data\ProviderBase\DbConnectionFactory.cs:line 138
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) in H:\tsaagent1\_work\21\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netcore\src\Microsoft\Data\ProviderBase\DbConnectionPool.cs:line 726
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) in H:\tsaagent1\_work\21\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netcore\src\Microsoft\Data\ProviderBase\DbConnectionPool.cs:line 1737
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) in H:\tsaagent1\_work\21\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netcore\src\Microsoft\Data\ProviderBase\DbConnectionPool.cs:line 1147
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) in H:\tsaagent1\_work\21\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netcore\src\Microsoft\Data\ProviderBase\DbConnectionPool.cs:line 1115
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) in H:\tsaagent1\_work\21\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netcore\src\Microsoft\Data\ProviderBase\DbConnectionFactory.cs:line 155
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) in H:\tsaagent1\_work\21\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netcore\src\Common\src\Microsoft\Data\ProviderBase\DbConnectionInternal.cs:line 338
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) in H:\tsaagent1\_work\21\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netcore\src\Common\src\Microsoft\Data\ProviderBase\DbConnectionClosed.cs:line 39
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides) in H:\tsaagent1\_work\21\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netcore\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlConnection.cs:line 1611
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open(SqlConnectionOverrides overrides) in H:\tsaagent1\_work\21\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netcore\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlConnection.cs:line 1115
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.<Exists>b__0(DateTime giveUp)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`2.<Execute>b__0(DbContext c, TState s)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, TState state, Func`2 operation, Func`2 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, TState state, Func`2 operation)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean retryOnNotExists)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)
```

Connection strings I tried:

```
Server=localhost,1433;Database=TenderDev;User Id=sa;Password=pass;
Server=localhost\\sqlexpress,1433;Database=TenderDev;User Id=sa;Password=pass;
Server=localhost;Database=TenderDev;User Id=sa;Password=pass;
Server=127.0.0.1,1433;Database=TenderDev;User Id=sa;Password=pass;
Server=xxx,1433;Database=TenderDev;User Id=sa;Password=pass;
```

All variations that I could find and none of them worked, I always get the same message. Which is strange, because I can connect to SQL Server from VS Code with just localhost, username and password with no problem and do all operations I need on the database. I also can connect to SQL Server using tools like:

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P "pass" -Q "SELECT @@Version"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU15) (KB5008996) - 15.0.4198.2 (X64) 
    Jan 12 2022 22:30:08 
    Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
    Express Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS) <X64>
```

If anyone knows why I can not connect from WebAPI, Entity Framework, ... please respond.

Thank you

Comment: It's apparently not 1433. Try just Server=localhost\\sqlexpress;Database=TenderDev;User

Comment: can you try this ```"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost,1433;Database= TenderDev;User ID=sa;Password=pass;Trusted_Connection=false;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },```

Comment: Same not working, I tried all variations with port, without port, port is 1433 i checked it, it works fine on windows, but it must work on linux too.

Comment: does not matter if i add MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Trusted_Connection=false or Integrated Security=False, nothing seems to work

Comment: Is the webapp running on the Ubuntu host, or could it be running inside a Docker container?

Comment: everything is running on Ubuntu host (not VM). I tried MSSQL on docker same results, i did not try webapp on docker, because i am developing it locally.